# Chrome devtools - how to move horizontally when simulating a retina screen

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

I'm basically trying to simulate a MacBook retina 15" display rendering by changing settings on simulations. The settings I'm using are 2880 x 1800. DPR 2.0. It might be a silly question, but when I simulate the 100% zoom the screen is too large for my monitor (despite being 27 inches), I think that happens because of the pixel density. All I want to know is how to move horizontally while on simulation, so I can check how images are looking (fuzzy or not). As an example, I'm inspecting apple's iPhone 7 website and I can only scroll down, using the down key on my keyboard or the scrolling button.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reproduced it. That appears to be a bug.

I also tried using the `Desktop (Touch)` to see if I could click and drag to horizontally scroll, but that doesn't work either.

Issue filed: https://crbug.com/677671